# Google Fusion Tables - How to get ROWID in media download

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I am querying a fusion table using a request like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/query?alt=media&sql=SELECT ROWID,State,County,Name,Location,Geometry,[... many more ...] FROM <table ID>
```

The results from this query exceed 10MB, so I must include the `alt=media` option (for smaller queries, where I can remove this option, the problem does not exist).  The response is in csv, as promised by the documentation.  The first line of the response appears to be a header line which exactly matches my query string (except that it shows `rowid` instead of `ROWID`):

```
rowid,State,County,Name,Location,Geometry,[... many more ...]
```

The following rows however do not include the row id.  Each line begins with the second item requested in the query - it seems as though the row id was ignored:

```
WV,Calhoun County,"Calhoun County, WV, USA",38.858 -81.1196,"<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs>...
```

Is there any way around this?  How can I retrieve row ids from a table when the table is large?

Answer (score 0):

Missing ROWIDs are also present for "media" requests made via [Google's Python API Client library](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/fusiontables/v2/python/latest/), e.g.

```
def doGetQuery(query):
    request = FusionTables.query().sqlGet_media(sql = query);
    response = request.execute();
    ft = {'kind': "fusiontables#sqlresponse"};
    s = queryResult.decode();    # bytestring to string
    data = [];
    for i in s.splitlines():
        data.append(i.split(','));
    ft['columns'] = data.pop(0); # ['Rowid', 'A', 'B', 'C'] 
    ft['rows'] = data;           # [['a1', 'b1', 'c1'], ...]
    return ft;
```

You may at least have one fewer issue than I - this `sqlGet_media` method can only be made with a "pure" GET request - a query long enough (2 - 8k characters) to get sent as overridden POST generates a `502 Bad Gateway` error, even for tiny response sizes such as the result from `SELECT COUNT()`. The same query as a non-media request works flawlessly (provided the response size is not over 10 MB, of course).

The solution to both your and my issue is to batch the request using `OFFSET` and `LIMIT`, such that the 10 MB response limit isn't hit. Estimate the size of an average response row at the call site, pass it into a wrapper function, and let the wrapper handle adding OFFSET and LIMIT to your input SQL, and then collate the multi-query result into a single output of the desired format:

```
def doGetQuery(query, rowSize = 1.):
    limitValue = floor(9.5 * 1024 / rowSize) # rowSize in kB
    offsetValue = 0;
    ft = {'kind': "fusiontables#sqlresponse"};
    data = [];
    done = False;
    while not done:
        tail = ' '.join(['OFFSET', str(offsetValue), 'LIMIT', str(limitValue)]);
        request = FusionTables.query().sqlGet(sql = query + ' ' + tail);
        response = request.execute();
        offsetValue += limitValue;
        if 'rows' in response.keys():
            data.extend(response['rows']);
        # Check the exit condition.
        if 'rows' not in response.keys() or len(response['rows']) < limitValue:
            done = True;
        if 'columns' not in ft.keys() and 'columns' in response.keys():
            ft['columns'] = response['columns'];

    ft['rows'] = data;
    return ft;
```

This wrapper can be extended to handle actual desired uses of offset and limit. Ideally for FusionTable or other REST API methods they provide a list() and list_next() method for native pagination, but no such features are present for FusionTable::Query. Given the horrendously slow rate of FusionTable API / functionality updates, I wouldn't expect ROWIDs to magically appear in `alt=media` downloads, or for GET-turned-POST media-format queries to ever work, so writing your own wrapper is going to save you a lot of headache.